# WPF - How do I bind a ViewModel to a View with parameters in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've been reviewing over Josh Smith's code (from his well-known MVVM article)recently, and I've been trying to create a program that follows his ideal MVVM pattern.

Now here's the problem, in Josh Smith's project's MainWindowResources, he binds the View to the (just using an arbitrary name here) ExampleViewModel, so the TabControl (workspaces) shows the ExampleView instead of just the .ToString() of ExampleViewModel. Example:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ExampleViewModel}">
  <vw:ExampleView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Normally this piece of code would work when the View doesn't take in any parameters. But for this project I take in the ViewModel in the View's constructor parameters:

```
public ExampleView(ExampleViewModel viewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

So now, I'm at a stand still- this type of binding only allows for parameter-less constructors.

**So how do I get around this problem, while still binding a View to a ViewModel, in which said View has constructor parameters?**

Comment: There are many questions already on Stack Overflow relating to general use of MVVM, including ones that discuss getting around the limitation of not being able to specify parameters to constructors when binding in XAML, such as the one I've provided as the duplicate link.

Comment: @PeterDuniho the added link at the top does not aswer this question. But I agree, there are many threads dealing with MVVM aspects.

Comment: I´m assuming you didn´t understand my question, so I´ll take it that my question is NOT a duplicate until you can give me an appropriate link with the right answer to my specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I think assigning a DataContext through contructor parameter might not be a great idea since that is automatically done by the dataTemplate***, but for any other parameter,hope the below suggestion helps!
First thing first, if you want to use `ExampleView` in XAML, then you need to have **a default constructor**, so the above constructor(mentioned in your question) is **not** going to work.
I would suggest you to define a dependency property with name *ViewModel* in `ExampleView`, and then use it from XAML. Something like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
    (
         "ViewModel", 
         typeof(ExampleViewModel), 
         typeof(ExampleView), 
         new PropertyMetadata(null)
    );

    public ExampleViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (ExampleViewModel)GetValue(ViewModelProperty ); }
        set { SetValue(ViewModelProperty , value); }
    }

    public ExampleView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //..........
```

}

Then you can write this in XAML:

```
<vw:ExampleView ViewModel="{Binding}" />
```

Comment: Thank you! I haven't really been introduced to DepencyProperties and how they work yet. But I'll take it for granite this works, and learn more on how and why this solution works tomorrow. Anyway, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Welcome ! in case you need any help with that, feel free to reach me :)